# Visual Studio crashing when i change .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, crash

I am working on a Visual Studio MVC project. (Version = 2013 )

When I try to write any javascript code in .js file or .cshtml file Visual Studio crashing and restarting.

When I open **Menu > Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript**  menu and disable "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" the problem is solving.(There is no any crashing)

[image: Screenshot-1]

But I cant see properties of javascript functions on editor. (Because i disabled it to remove crashing error on previous step.I have already tried to delete .suo file and rebuild solution method but not worked on my project. There is still crashing if i write javascript code. )

How can I solve this crashing problem without disable to Auto list members" and "Parameter information" properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Resharper and had the same problem,  the solution whas to deactivate Intellisense in Resharper => Options => Environment => IntelliSense => General for .js files

Answer (score 0):

Restart Visual Studio in Administrator mode.
If the same issue still occurs, try to move your project to another directory.

Comment: I did it now. There is same crashing if i write "blabla" in javascript file. Even if i change comment  line, Visual Studio crashing again :)))))

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem few months ago, I could not find the answer so I tried to install another version of VS. Installing Visual Studio 2017 solved it.

Comment: I think Its very expensive solution.

Comment: I know, but I had to do it because I couldn't find another solution.

Comment: @c_atlantis Expensive in terms of time, maybe, but not money. If you're a solo dev or in a small company you can get VS 2017 Community Edition for free and it is not far short of the Professional SKU https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/